# Sub-String replace issue

Tags: java, android, string, str-replace

I have a String that can assume two forms

First form

```
 file:///mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile.txt
```

Second form

```
 /file://mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile.txt
```

And I need the String always in the form

```
/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile.txt
```

So I have used the replace command

```
myPath=path.replace("file://", "");
myPath= path.replace("/file:/", "");
```

But unfortunately doesn't work

and String myPath results

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile.txt
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Actually, if the strings are in the forms you say, the first replace command should take care of both cases. Don't believe me? Really look at it...if you take 'file://' out of both of them, in the first case, the third '/' is left, and in the second, the leading '/' is still there. I know you have already resolved your issue, but I thought I should point this out. myPath=path.replace("file://", ""); should take care of both cases...just delete the second statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're guaranteed that your string will always be in one of those two forms, why not just use

```
myPath = path.substring(path.indexOf("/mnt"));
```

If you're not sure your path contains "/mnt", you could try this:

```
if (path.contains("file:"))
{
    myPath = path.substring(path.indexOf(":/") + 1);
    while (myPath.startsWith("//"))
        myPath = myPath.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 
this seems a good solution but if the file is in internal phone archive folder and not in the SD card I'm not sure that the path starts with /mnt... Could you confirm this?

Comment: Edited my post with an alternate solution for if you're not sure that the path contains "/mnt"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
path=path.replace("file://", "");
myPath= path.replace("/file:/", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this... but Why in this form should works?

Comment: Because as svz said, the second replace you're doing is overwriting the first. You need to apply all your replaces to the same variable, and then assign the result to myPath.

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite the first `myPath = path.replace()` call with the second call which probably replaces nothing and returns you the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

This surely gives you what you want:

```
String mypath=path.replaceFirst("[/]?file://[/]?","/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
path = path.replaceAll("^(file://|/file:/)", "");
```

Or:

```
myPath=path.replace("file://", "");
myPath= **myPath**.replace("/file:/", "");
```